In a VSCode workspace containing multiple python packages, is it possible for VSCode to respect a different .flake8 for each package?
I have a VSCode workspace that contains multiple packages from different organizations. They use different coding standards and, therefor, have different .flake8 files. Is there a way to get VSCode to respect each .flake8 file in its respective package?
For example, take the workspace directory structure below. Assume that .flake8 specifies:

79 character lines for package1 and
88 character lines for package2.

Is there a way to get VSCode to correctly respect the code standards of each of these two packages?
.
├── package1
│   ├── .flake8
│   ├── package1
│   └── pyproject.toml
└── package2
    ├── .flake8
    ├── package2
    └── pyproject.toml


In https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-flake8/issues/194 there is a workaround may help you which uses multi-root workspace feature of VSCode.You can also specify configuration file in"flake8.args".
